# Spotify Web API - Client Credentials - Accessing a users playlists

Tags: php, api, oauth, spotify

I'm trying to access users playlist tracks by using the client credentials flow.

Spotify getting playlist documentation: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlists-tracks/

Spotify getting client credentials documentation: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

First question, is it possible to get a users playlist tracks using client credentials flow? I'm using this flow since I'm unable to pop up a login box for the user to login.

Secondly, I've tried using https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php client credentials flow (Docs: http://jwilsson.github.io/spotify-web-api-php/authorization.html) by practically copying the code at the bottom of that page:

```
    <?php

include('vendor/autoload.php');

$session = new SpotifyWebAPI\Session('Tobys client id', 'Tobys secret', 'http://localhost/callback');
// Request a access token with optional scopes
$scopes = array(
    'playlist-read-private',
    'user-read-private'
);

$session->requestCredentialsToken($scopes);
$accessToken = $session->getAccessToken(); // We're good to go!

// Set the code on the API wrapper
$api->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$playlists = $api->getUserPlaylists('USER_ID', array(
    'limit' => 5
));

foreach ($playlists->items as $playlist) {
    echo '<a href="' . $playlist->external_urls->spotify . '">' . $playlist->name . '</a> <br>';
}
```

This gives me `Notice: Undefined variable: api in /var/www/html/dev/testing.php on line 16`

I've also tried creating the API variable using `$api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();` but this says I need user information/ tokens.

Thanks.

Comment: For the $api, try referencing this https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php/blob/master/tests/SpotifyWebAPITest.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First question, is it possible to get a users playlist tracks using
>   client credentials flow?

Yes, retrieving tracks for a playlist doesn't require user authentication as part of the access token.

> I've also tried creating the API variable using $api = new
>   SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI(); but this says I need user information/
>   tokens.

Looking at the code ([Session class](https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php/blob/master/src/Session.php), [SpotifyWebapi class](https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php/blob/master/src/SpotifyWebAPI.php)), it does look like you should set this up by doing

```
$api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();
$session = new SpotifyWebAPI\Session($clientId, $clientSecret, $redirectUri);
$api->setAccessToken($session->getAccessToken());
```

When that's set up you should be good to use the `getUserPlaylists` method like you're doing in your example code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can confirm this works. When I change the USER_ID in the code above to my username, it works perfectly. However, when I change this to someone else's username whom I know has playlists, there playlists don't show up... Is the playlist grabbing only for whoever owns the client id? If so, how can I get OTHER users playlists?

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Using an access token received using the Client Credentials flow will only return USER_ID's public playlists - my guess is that the USER_ID you're providing only has private playlists. The only way to retrieve private playlists is to use an access token authenticated by the user, and to have the user authorize the `playlist-read-private` scope.